# Change Jquery control.classname to control.addclass

Tags: jquery

In the code below, I don't want to replace the entire class of the control I just want to add and remove class.

I have tried

```
control.addClass = "form-control-Error login-form-control col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12";
```

But it is not working.

```
 var control = document.getElementById(Page_Validators[i].controltovalidate);
                        if (!Page_Validators[i].isvalid) {

                            control.className = "form-control-Error login-form-control col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12";
                        } else {
                            control.className = "login-form-control col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12";


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap `control` in jQuery object and `addClass()` is a method:

```
$(control).addClass("form-control-Error login-form-control col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could utilize the [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) property:

```
control.classList.add('form-control-Error')
```

Here's a sample:

```js
document.getElementById('target').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('target').classList.add('second-class');
})
```

```css
.first-class{
  font-weight: bold;
}
.second-class{
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<span id="target" class="first-class">Click me!</span>
```

Comment: No need to use jQuery in the case OP **just** wants to add class(es). I completly forgot about this method, this should be accepted answer imho ;)

Comment: @A.Wolff I don't see this in use often myself... Maybe people don't see this as "backwards compatible" enough...

Comment: Indeed, the shim for backward compatibilities is quite weird imo